# How to remove rails 3.2.16 after install it using apt-get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just installed rails using "apt-get". But I want to using rails 5.0.2.
After that I installed rails using:

```
sudo gem install rails -v 5.0.2
```

and it return message:

```
Successfully installed rails-5.0.2
```

But when I type "rails -v", the version still 3.2.16.

I am a new member of Rails.

Thanks for any help.

Vien.

Comment: Try installing without sudo

Comment: I tried but "You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory"

Comment: You should check out rbenv or alternatively, rvm.  Both of those install ruby versions (and gems) in your directories.

Comment: gem: 2.6.11,  rvm: 1.29.1, rbenv: 1.1.0.  I think my fault is install rails using "apt-get". And now I don't know how to upgrade rails or remove it and reinstall. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open the gemfile of your repository/service/code , and within it add this line of code :

```
ruby-gemset=rails-5.0.2
```

after which in command prompt enter:

> rvm use @rails-5.0.2

This should work, can you respond if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for support, I added "ruby-gemset=rails-5.0.2" to Gemfile(in my project) and type "rvm use @rails-5.0.2" in terminal but t didn't work for me.

I think my fault is intall rails using "apt-get". And now I don't know how to upgrade rails or remove it and reinstall.